# Help with Haskell dynamic plugin load

Tags: plugins, haskell, dynamic-loading

I'm a Haskell beginner, and I'm trying to use the dynamic loading in the 'plugins' package.  I'm kind of lost.  Here is a minimal program with two files.

Main.hs:

```
module Main (main) where

import System.Plugins

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Loading"
  mv <- dynload "Plug.o" [] [] "thing"   -- also try 'load' here
  putStrLn "Loaded"
  case mv of
    LoadFailure msgs -> putStrLn "fail" >> print msgs
    LoadSuccess _ v -> putStrLn "success" >> print (v::Integer)
```

And Plug.hs:

```
module Plug (thing) where

thing :: Integer
thing = 1234000
```

I compile Plug with `ghc -c Plug.hs` which produces Plug.o.  I then compile Main.hs with `ghc -o Main Main.hs`, and run Main.  I also try replacing `load` with `dynload`, and running with `runhaskell`.  Only one of these four combinations works.  What am I doing wrong?

- with `dynload`

  - compiled → prints "Loaded", then seg faults
  - runhaskell → prints "Loading", then "Main.hs: Prelude.undefined"
- with `load`

  - compiled → successful, prints the Integer
  - runhaskell → prints "Loading", hangs for 5-10 seconds, disappears

I'm on Mac OS X.  GHC version 7.0.2.  What am I doing wrong?

thanks,
Rob

### Update

I can fix the compiled `dynload` by changing Plug.hs to the following...

```
module Plug (thing) where
import Data.Dynamic                                                                                                    
thing :: Dynamic
thing = toDyn (1234000::Integer)
```

It would be nice if it didn't seg fault on error.  I guess it doesn't have enough meta data in Plug.o to check the type.   Anyway, that leaves the `runhaskell` cases.  I filed a [bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5053) for those.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried your example under Ubuntu 10.10 with GHC 6.12.1 and the results are: both `dynload` and `load` with running both complied or through `runhaskell` gives me "Prelude.undefined" error, so I think you should report a bug to the developers.

I cannot see any special cases nor conditions in their module's [haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.1.4/doc/html/System-Plugins-Load.html) documentation, so I don't think you doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at a similar problem with the GHC-API on [haskell ghc dynamic compliation only works on first compile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790341/haskell-ghc-dynamic-compliation-only-works-on-first-compile)