# Haskell plugins package on Windows Not x86 PEi386 error

Tags: windows, haskell, plugins

I'm trying to get the plugins package to work on Windows.

I have windows Vista 64 bit. I installed the latest Haskell Platform today (which ghc --version says 7.0.4). I installed the latest cygwin.

I run a simple example (specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427777/help-with-haskell-dynamic-plugin-load) and after fixing various things (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795147/haskell-plugins-package-on-windows-adddll-error)) I get this error:

```
Main.exe: Plug.dll: Not x86 PEi386
Main.exe: user error (Could not load module `Plug.dll')
```

I'm not sure where to go with this one.

I compiled the dll and test code in the same way, smae ghc:

```
ghc -shared -o Plug.dll Plug.hs
ghc -package ghc -o Main Main.hs
```

Also, I used InspectExe to check and it says the Plug.dll file is a 32 bit dll and it was able to load it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GHC does not support compiling 64-bit binaries on Windows platforms ([#1884](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1884)). All executables produced by GHC are 32-bit on Windows. This means that you can only link against 32-bit DLLs. Apparently, your compiled DLL wasn't compiled as 32-bit, which probably is because you used a different compiler other than MinGW to produce the DLL.

Comment: Thanks, but according to InspectExe, it is a 32bit dll.